# SQL efficiency with multiple table joins with an aggregate

Tags: sql, oracle, join, aggregate

I have 3 tables involved in this:
Tickets, Relation, Clocks.

I need to get the ticket_id from the TICKETS table, join that to the RELATIONS table to get the related incident_id (if there is one) and then join the incident_id to the CLOCKS table and add up all the "open" time for that incident_id.

The clocks table will have the incident_id listed multiple times for each clock name (open, work in progress, scheduled, pending customer, pending change, pending vendor, resolved), so I have to group by the incident_id and sum(clock_time).

This is what I wrote that works, but the run time is quite long, even for a single ticket:

```
Select
TBL1.Ticket_ID,
TBL1.Related_Incident,
TBL2.Total_Open_Clocks
From
  (
   Select
   TICKETS.Ticket_ID,
   RELATIONS.Related_incident
   From 
   TICKETS left join RELATIONS ON
   TICKETS.Ticket_ID = RELATIONS.Ticket_ID
   WHERE
   Ticket_ID  =  'SDW123')  as TBL1

Left Join
  (
   SELECT
   Incident_Id,
   SUM(clock_time) as Total_Open_Clocks
   FROM
   CLOCKS
   Where clock_type In ('Open', 'Work In Progress', 'Pending Vendor')
   Group by Incident_Id) as TBL2  
on
TBL1.Related_Incident = TBL2.Incident_Id
```

If I run the first query separately, it runs in about 1 second. If I run the second query separately it runs in about 1 second. The full query took about 10 mins for a single ticket.

So is there anything I can do to optimize this to run faster? I don't have the ability make a new table or temp tables.

Comment: Can and will you generate an execution plan? Its ok to say no, so then I would waste my type explaining how to do it.

Comment: No, I can't generate an execution plan. I only have read-only rights.

Comment: That might be enough. Try this.  alter session set statistics_level=ALL; then run your query; then run this...  select * from table( dbms_xplan.display_cursor( null, null, 'ALLSTATS LAST' ) );

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the query:

```
SELECT    tk.Ticket_ID,
          rl.Related_incident,
          clk.Total_Open_Clocks
FROM      TICKETS tk 
LEFT JOIN RELATIONS rl
ON        tk.Ticket_ID = rl.Ticket_ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   Incident_Id,
                    SUM(clock_time) as Total_Open_Clocks
           FROM     CLOCKS
           WHERE    clock_type In ('Open', 'Work In Progress', 'Pending Vendor')
           GROUP BY Incident_Id) clk
ON         clk.Incident_Id = rl.Related_incident
WHERE      Ticket_ID  =  'SDW123'
```

As far I suppose you have an index on TICKETS(Ticked_ID), and on RELATIONS(Related_incident).

Try by adding an index on CLOCKS(Incident_id, clock_type).

Comment: Thanks. I actually started out with something like this, it's possible I wasn't patient enough to let it finish so I scrapped it and started over. I will check and see what the indexes are on the tables but I don't have any rights besides read-only.

Answer (score 0):

May be:

```
Select TICKETS.Ticket_ID, RELATIONS.Related_Incident,
       sum(TBL2.clock_time) as Total_Open_Clocks
  From TICKETS
  left join RELATIONS ON TICKETS.Ticket_ID = RELATIONS.Ticket_ID
  left join CLOCKS TBL2
    ON TBL2.Incident_Id=RELATIONS.Related_Incident
   and TBL2.clock_type In ('Open', 'Work In Progress', 'Pending Vendor')
 WHERE TICKETS.Ticket_ID  =  'SDW123'
 Group by TICKETS.Ticket_ID, RELATIONS.Related_Incident
```

If this give incorrect result, show the structure of the tables and sample data. if query time is long - show [`explain plan`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm)

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a shot as well as look into explain plan. From the little bit of reading I've just done I may not be able to use it since I don't think I have insert or delete privileges .